# JS duplicate entry with every form submission

Tags: javascript

When I add a new name, it works but when I added one again it adds it twice and so on.... it seems to be caused by the popup but I don't get why?

```js
let table = document.getElementById('table')
let popup = document.querySelector('.popup')
let add_new_form = document.querySelector('#form-new')
let add_btn = document.querySelector('.add')

add_btn.addEventListener('click', add_new)

function add_new() {
  popup.classList.remove('hidden')
  add_new_form.classList.remove('hidden')

  add_new_form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let new_name   = add_new_form.querySelector('#name-new-input').value

    table.innerHTML += `<p>${new_name}</p>`
    popup.classList.add('hidden')
  })
}
```

```css
.hidden {display:none}
.popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000c;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.popup-box {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button class="add">Add</button>

<div id="table" class=""></div>

<div class="popup hidden">
  <div class="popup-box">
    <form id="form-new">
      <input type="text" id="name-new-input">
      <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're binding a new 'submit' addEventListener every time you call the add_new function. Move that listener outside of the function. https://jsfiddle.net/qod19a7p/1/

Comment: You also shouldn't be using a `form`, the `submit` event, or `e.preventDefault()` here since you aren't actually submitting data anywhere. Regular buttons and their `click` events are all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Every time* you were running the `add_new` function, you were binding a new Event Listener to `add_new_form`

Bind the Event Listener outside of the function, and instead trigger the submit event in the `add_new` function

```js
let table = document.getElementById('table')
let popup = document.querySelector('.popup')
let add_new_form = document.querySelector('#form-new')
let add_btn = document.querySelector('.add')

add_btn.addEventListener('click', function add_new() {
  popup.classList.remove('hidden')
  add_new_form.classList.remove('hidden')

  // Trigger the submit event
  add_new_form.submit;
})

add_new_form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let new_name = add_new_form.querySelector('#name-new-input').value

  table.innerHTML += `<p>${new_name}</p>`
  popup.classList.add('hidden')
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}

.popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000c;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.popup-box {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button class="add">Add</button>

<div id="table" class=""></div>

<div class="popup hidden">
  <div class="popup-box">
    <form id="form-new">
      <input type="text" id="name-new-input">
      <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You see the same behavior on that link if you press the top 'Add' button more than once